# Interaction between Web application an AMI Asterisk

Tags: sip, asterisk

I have developped a web application that allows people to make call from web to a VoiP System based on Asterisk with only a click ( it is like a click to call ) 
But all the calls that come from the app are issued from the same SIP Account. So I created 3 fields to enter some informations ( Name, phone number , Email) these informations are put in Asterisk database before making the call .
What i want is that the name and the phone number may be shown instead of the SIP account from which the call is initied.
How can I use the AMI to allow this function .

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Are you using "Action: Originate" from a channel to an extension ?

```
Action: Originate
Channel: SIP/1001
Context: default
Exten: 1000
Priority: 1
Timeout: 30000
```

If yes

You will need use one AGI or [Mysql Function](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+MYSQL) to get the values from your database, and then set [CALLERID(name,num)](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Setting+Callerid)

set in you extensions.conf

```
[default] 
exten => 1000,1,AGI(AGI_TO_GET_VALUES_FROM_DATABASE)    
exten => 1000,n,Set(${CALLERID(NUM)}=${VARIABLE_NUM_FORM_AGI})    
exten => 1000,n,Set(${CALLERID(NAME)}=${VARIABLE_NAME_FROM_AGI})    
exten => 1000,n,Dial(...)
```

One Another way is set the "variable" param and pass to your exten:

```
Action: Originate
Channel: SIP/1001
Context: default
Exten: 1000
Priority: 1
Timeout: 30000
Variable: var1=23|var2=24
```

Put into var1,var2 the values from your database!

Now you can get var1,var2 in your extensions.conf and set callerid(name,num)

You still can set the "Callerid" param to set your phone number like:

```
Action: Originate
Channel: SIP/1001
Context: default
Exten: 1000
Priority: 1
Timeout: 30000
Callerid: 111111
Variable: var1=23|var2=24
```

Comment: Never use mysql function,it is depricated. User REALTIME instead of that.